# How can I vizualize a dataframe with count data from categorical variables?

Tags: r, visualization, categorical-data, graph-visualization, ggnetwork

I have a dataframe from an experiment with the stimuli on the columns and responses (in the form of one word) from participants in the rows. Each participant saw each one of the stimuli. The dataframe is filled with counts of how many times that response was given for a stimulus. A zero is coded when a specific response is never given for a specific stimulus. It looks like this:

| S | angry | happy | sad | excited | frustrated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| b | 0 | 0 | 0 | 15 | 0 |
| c | 5 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| d | 2 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 6 |

I wanted to visualize this data and I tried a bunch of different solutions: correspondence analysis, factor analysis, networks, MDS.  All of those that I tried take a distance matrix as an input, where simuli are in a dissimilarity stimuli-by-stimuli matrix with a number that represents the distance based on the responses, but in this way I loose the info on the emotions. Is there any way I can work with this table to retain the info on stimuli + emotions + how many times an emotion is linked to a stimulus?

Comment: 0 means no response and should  be discarded? And provided sample should result with 2 edges, *happy-angry* and *sad-frustrated*, edge weights for both being 2 (count of equal responses, (1,1) for the 1st and (5,5) for 2nd) ?

Comment: Can you add the  igraph and ggnet code ypu wrote and what you want the network to look like to your question?